# How do I open port 10000 on Amazon EC2 to access webmin?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have managed to successfully set up on Amazon Machine Instance (AMI) runnint Ubuntu 10.0.4 on Amazon EC2. I have setup the default security group to allow SSH and HTTPS access and these seem to be working correctly.

However, I am unable to access webmin using the following URL

https://:10000/

I have added port 10000 to iptables and ensured that webmin is running. I can run

curl https://localhost:10000

and get a response on the AMI.

I setup security group for port 10000 like so

1. Selected HTTPS in the connection dropdown (port number is set to 443)
2. Changed 443 to 10000 in both To and From boxes
3. Added 0.0.0.0/0 to the allow IP box
4. Hit save and the entry looks like so

-- tcp 10000 10000 0.0.0.0/0

Anything else I am missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue has now been magically resolved. Here is what I did

1. Restarted AMI
2. Assigned an Elastic IP
3. Deleted the -- tcp 10000 10000 0.0.0.0/0 entry from the Security Groups list in AMI console
4. Added entry to security group for port 10000. However this time, I chose Custom in the first drop down. The entry created reads -- tcp 10000 10000 0.0.0.0/0
5. SSH login into AMI
6. Reload iptables to open port access to 10000
7. Restarted webmin
8. Browsed to https://:10000 and IT WORKED!

HTH

Comment: never become a magician :)

Answer (score 0):

Add new inbound rule in security group of Amazon ec2 instance.

```
 Custom TCP Rule   TCP     10000      0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! I edited your first answer a bit, fixing the formatting.

Comment: Welcome for changes.